# Kendo UI scheduler - Right click on cells deselects selection

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I have the problem mentioned above.

I want to create a little context menu on scheduler. When I click on selected cells.

The problem is than when i right click selected cells, it selects only one cell that was clicked and deselects the other ones.

Is there a solution for that ?

Answer (score 2):

By default kendo scheduler supports single selection. There is no specific option to set multiple selection.To have multiple selection hold the "Shift" key + mouse click.

Once multiple slot are got selected follow the same approach to add an appointment.
i.e
  "Shift" key + rightclick on the last selected slot and the context menu will popup for the whole selection.

Also, to get the multiple selected slot start and end time define "change" function of scheduler:

```
          change: function (e) {
                var startTime = e.start;
                var endTime = e.end;
            }
```

Hope this helps.